# Java Lucene NRT search not working

Tags: java, lucene, lucene-nrt

Playing around with Lucene. Trying to make my changes visible for other reading threads. Without rebuilding index. For that purpose i use SearcherManager class.

Creation of manager

```
Directory index = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(LUCENE_INDEX_PATH));
w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
indexReader = IndexReader.open(w, true);
manager = new SearcherManager(w, true, null, null);
```

Update request

```
w.updateDocument(t, document);
manager.maybeReopen(); // openIfChanged same behavior
w.commit();
```

Search request

```
IndexSearcher searcher = manager.acquire();
try {
    return performSearch(query, searcher, skip, limit);
} finally {
    manager.release(searcher);
    searcher = null;
}
```

Changes are flushed to disc, but new search request see them only after application restart (recreation of index). Looks like IndexSearcher  still point to old Index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to open your own IndexReader; just create the SearcherManager (from your IndexWriter) then use acquire/release from it, to get a searcher/reader.

After adding/deleting docs with the writer, you should call maybeReopen, and then the next time you call SearcherManager.acquire the returned searcher will reflect the changes.  It's best to use a background thread (ie, not a thread doing searching) to index docs and call maybeReopen.

You don't need to call IndexWriter.commit to make changes visible -- only call this when you require durability (ie, that all changes are safely on disk and will survive OS/JVM crash, power loss, kill -9, etc.).

Comment: Yes, separate indexReader is just a legacy code, removed. I know exactly, when changes are made, so it is preferable for me, call maybeReopen in same thread. Now the only one problem with deleting document by Term. Documents are not deleted from index Could you please suggest common pattern for deleting ? Probably better mark "as deleted" in index, and just make update of document

Comment: If you call IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(Term), and then open a new NRT reader (passing true for applyAllDeletes), then the deletion should be reflected.  Are you sure you have the right Term?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NRT search use different SearcherManager constructor that takes an IndexWriter as parameter. Check this article http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html

Comment: It does not change anything for me. I tried another constructor with Writer

Comment: Are you sure? And you need not even commit to be able to search for the newly added documents.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, i should not create IndexReader.

```
indexReader = IndexReader.open(w, true)
```

If I remove this line, everything works. Dunno why yet